# Program compiles but crashes when using floating point

Tags: c++

So I am working with this simple block of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int sum_of_squares (double a, double b)
{
    double sum;
    double sum1;
    sum1 = pow(a,2)+pow(b,2);
    sum = sqrt(sum1);
    return sum;
}
int main ()
{
    //User Inputs
    double x1;
    double x2;
    double y1;
    double y2;
    double r1;
    double r2;
    double diffx;
    double diffy;
    cout << "Enter the information for the first circle";
    cout << "x-coordinate:";
    cin >> x1; 
    cout << "y-coordinate:";
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "radius:";
    cin >> r1;
    cout << "Enter the information for the second circle";
    cout << "x-coordinate:";
    cin >> x2; 
    cout << "y-coordinate:";
    cin >> y2;
    cout << "radius:";
    cin >> r2;

    //Math
    double total_radius;
    double circle_sep;
    double difference;
    diffx = abs(x1-x2);
    diffy = abs(y1-y2);
    total_radius = r1+r2;
    circle_sep = sum_of_squares(diffx,diffy);
    difference = circle_sep - total_radius;

    //Outputs
    int z;
    if(total_radius>circle_sep)
        cout<< "THE CIRCLES OVERLAP.";
    else
        cout << difference;
        cout << "THE MINIMUM DISTANCE BETWEEN THE CIRCLES IS " << difference << ".";
    cout << "Enter 0 to exit";
    cin>> z;
    return 0;
}
```

The first output if statement works perfectly, even when giving it coordinates that would require floating point math. The else statement after that is not working as well. I can get the program to compile and run when I remove the "cout << difference", but when I deliberately enter circles that are separated the program crashes. I can't get the program to compile if I leave that line of code in there. To me it seems like the computer should be able to do a simple line of subtraction, but it crashes. I have another program with a similar issue that I hope the solution to this will apply to.

Thanks!

Comment: when you remove the `cout << difference;` line, it works?  Does the `cout << "THE MINIMUM DISTANCE BETWEEN THE CIRCLES IS " << difference << ".";` line produce the expected output?

Comment: It doesn't crash on me. Could you please provide some examples of input which do cause a crash?

Comment: Your `sum_of_squares` performs floating point calculations, but the result is truncated to an integer before it is returned.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the crash?  What were the values of the variables before the crash?

Comment: When I remove that line, the program compiles and I can enter whatever i want as long as the circles overlap. If I enter coordinates and radii that don't overlap, the program outputs " The minimum separation is:" then crashes.

Comment: You should replace the `pow` function calls with `a*a` and `b*b`.  The multiplication is much faster as it doesn't involve the overhead of calling a function and returning.

Comment: Why does your `sum_of_squares` return an `int` when the rest of the program uses `double`?

Comment: Could not replicate, no crashes (could use some line-ends in the prompts).  Answer is wrong for c1<0,0,1> and c2<2,2,1>.  Used g++ 4.8.2, on Cygwin, Windows 7.  The wrong result could be from the integer truncation from the `sum_of_squares` function.

Comment: I changed it to a*a+b*b and changed the function to return a double and it still compiles, accepts inputs, and crashes. Still works fine if the circles overlap.

Answer (score 0):

The program compiles fine for me on g++ 4.6.3

However, if you only want to output the `THE MINIMUM DISTANCE BETWEEN THE CIRCLES IS` message when `total_radius <= circle_sep`, you should put curly braces around those indented lines.